# convert csv to netcdf in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I have one .csv file with headers "time01", "latitude", "longitude" and "fro". The file has daily data of each grid. Now I want to convert into netcdf with coordinates ranging from 68E-98E and 5N-40N. The actual data is of 31 days But Here, I am giving data only of 9 days from 2009-01-01 to 2009-01-09 but

```
time01      lat     lon     frp
2009-01-01  30.037  80.572  38.5
2009-01-01  23.671  85.008  7.2
2009-01-01  22.791  86.206  11.4
2009-01-01  23.755  86.421  5.6
2009-01-01  23.673  86.088  4.2
2009-01-01  23.768  86.392  8.4
2009-01-01  23.789  86.243  7.8
2009-01-01  23.805  86.327  6.4
2009-01-01  23.682  86.085  7.8
2009-01-01  23.68   86.095  5.7
2009-01-01  21.194  81.41   19
2009-01-01  16.95   81.912  8
2009-01-01  16.952  81.898  11.5
2009-01-01  16.899  81.682  10.6
2009-01-01  12.994  79.651  16.1
2009-01-01  9.2 77.603  14.5
2009-01-01  12.291  77.346  20.5
2009-01-01  17.996  79.708  13.9
2009-01-01  17.998  79.718  29.6
2009-01-01  16.61   81.266  6.6
2009-01-01  16.499  81.2    6.8
2009-01-01  19.505  81.784  22.4
2009-01-01  18.322  80.555  7.7
2009-01-01  19.506  81.794  28.2
2009-01-01  21.081  81.957  8.7
2009-01-01  21.223  82.127  9.4
2009-01-01  20.918  81.025  6.3
2009-01-01  19.861  82.123  9.3
2009-01-01  20.62   75.049  11.6
2009-01-01  21.222  82.116  12
2009-01-01  21.608  82.338  8.3
2009-01-01  21.61   82.349  8.1
2009-01-01  21.655  84.081  8.4
2009-01-01  21.733  81.195  28.4
2009-01-01  21.819  81.84   6.2
2009-01-01  21.879  82.941  6.6
2009-01-01  21.731  81.185  18.3
2009-01-01  21.122  75.809  10.4
2009-01-01  21.218  76.557  8.2
2009-01-01  22.931  77.455  8.4
2009-01-01  22.843  77.541  17.7
2009-01-01  22.863  78.898  8.3
2009-01-01  22.865  78.907  9.5
2009-01-01  22.509  78.014  5.6
2009-01-01  22.797  86.204  13.3
2009-01-01  22.966  77.269  5.6
2009-01-01  24.201  82.714  14.5
2009-01-01  23.395  79.717  5.2
2009-01-01  24.148  82.617  7.9
2009-01-01  28.97   77.428  5.6
2009-01-01  27.017  78.44   7.1
2009-01-01  27.343  80.791  4.4
2009-01-01  25.525  75.636  9.8
2009-01-01  29.051  78.111  3.9
2009-01-01  27.942  79.886  3.5
2009-01-01  27.748  79.197  5.5
2009-01-01  27.475  79.347  3.8
2009-01-01  27.365  80.038  7.5
2009-01-01  27.977  80.812  4.4
2009-01-01  27.747  79.187  3.1
2009-01-01  28.088  78.201  4
2009-01-01  28.984  78.087  19.9
2009-01-01  28.221  79.156  3.7
2009-01-01  27.936  78.827  3.7
2009-01-01  28.068  78.521  5.8
2009-01-01  28.976  78.099  11.6
2009-01-01  28.291  77.638  3.5
2009-01-01  28.077  78.059  5.2
2009-01-01  28.272  78.134  7.6
2009-01-01  28.929  78.031  3.3
2009-01-01  28.29   77.628  5.8
2009-01-01  28.461  77.791  3.7
2009-01-01  31.102  77.904  6.7
2009-01-01  31.101  77.893  6.6
2009-01-01  31.104  77.914  6.1
2009-01-01  31.761  76.649  3.4
2009-01-01  31.063  78.018  8.5
2009-01-01  30.812  78.466  5.8
2009-01-01  30.659  78.019  6.1
2009-01-01  30.663  78.317  5.3
2009-01-01  30.604  78.496  5
2009-01-01  29.403  77.487  3.5
2009-01-01  29.997  76.889  12.8
2009-01-01  29.531  78.65   5.3
2009-01-01  29.027  77.563  3.5
2009-01-01  29.061  77.351  4.2
2009-01-01  29.033  77.604  3.8
2009-01-01  29.012  77.587  4.2
2009-01-01  29.101  77.688  6.8
2009-01-01  29.103  77.698  3.1
2009-01-01  29.074  77.825  12.6
2009-01-01  29.076  77.835  4
2009-01-01  29.057  77.578  5.7
2009-01-01  29.241  78.951  6.3
2009-01-01  28.992  77.203  5.7
2009-01-01  29.103  77.511  4.2
2009-01-01  29.66   79.697  5
2009-01-01  28.998  76.334  5.9
2009-01-01  29.175  77.758  4.8
2009-01-01  29  76.345  11.5
2009-01-01  29.164  77.43   10.5
2009-01-01  29.155  77.432  4
2009-01-01  29.181  77.542  5.4
2009-01-01  29.332  77.438  13.2
2009-01-01  29.303  77.365  3.5
2009-01-01  29.273  77.35   5.2
2009-01-01  29.184  77.374  3.7
2009-01-01  29.237  77.483  3.3
2009-01-01  29.349  77.56   3.3
2009-01-01  29.398  77.394  3.4
2009-01-01  29.401  77.477  3.6
2009-01-01  29.67   79.277  5.2
2009-01-01  29.415  77.506  6.6
2009-01-01  29.574  77.971  3.5
2009-01-01  29.455  77.271  3.1
2009-01-01  29.449  77.419  3.5
2009-01-01  29.64   77.527  3.4
2009-01-01  29.906  79.683  5.8
2009-01-01  29.543  77.248  4
2009-01-01  28.255  97.043  13.3
2009-01-01  28.192  97.064  16.3
2009-01-01  28.256  97.052  18.9
2009-01-01  14.045  75.67   5.6
2009-01-01  16.56   74.755  5.6
2009-01-01  16.368  75.517  17.9
2009-01-01  16.37   75.528  6.2
2009-01-01  15.954  75.028  7.6
2009-01-01  17.194  74.213  5.8
2009-01-01  17.499  74.089  14.3
2009-01-01  23.681  86.096  7.4
2009-01-01  23.682  86.086  8.9
2009-01-01  23.771  86.401  8.1
2009-01-01  22.33   82.669  8.3
2009-01-02  28.186  97.063  14.7
2009-01-02  25.758  94.841  14.8
2009-01-02  24.748  94.051  25.4
2009-01-02  24.759  94.035  22.7
2009-01-02  30.86   78.628  7.3
2009-01-02  30.804  78.505  10
2009-01-02  31.203  78.237  8.5
2009-01-02  30.665  78.318  5.4
2009-01-02  30.426  78.063  9.4
2009-01-02  28.583  80.455  6.8
2009-01-02  25.971  76.999  14.4
2009-01-02  28.139  80.48   8.3
2009-01-02  24.733  78.11   6.4
2009-01-02  24.145  82.617  7.6
2009-01-02  24.199  82.722  10.3
2009-01-02  23.418  79.289  6.2
2009-01-02  23.69   79.46   7.2
2009-01-02  22.321  69.88   36.7
2009-01-02  22.322  69.887  32.9
2009-01-02  22.324  69.867  12
2009-01-02  21.254  76.657  9.9
2009-01-02  18.547  74.569  8.6
2009-01-02  21.379  74.723  7.6
2009-01-02  18.549  74.559  6
2009-01-02  19.026  73.457  5.5
2009-01-02  21.584  72.944  8.5
2009-01-02  18.429  74.69   9.4
2009-01-02  18.427  74.699  5.4
2009-01-02  17.983  74.964  13
2009-01-02  17.756  75.316  62.8
2009-01-02  17.747  75.314  5.5
2009-01-02  17.755  75.325  67.3
2009-01-02  17.746  75.324  5.2
2009-01-02  17.024  77.158  8.9
2009-01-02  12.94   76.346  3.6
2009-01-02  14.03   75.442  7.2
2009-01-02  14.039  75.443  9.2
2009-01-02  12.741  76.376  4.7
2009-01-02  12.152  76.847  7.1
2009-01-02  12.349  76.579  6.6
2009-01-02  22.789  86.213  14.3
2009-01-02  23.362  91.398  5.8
2009-01-02  27.137  95.573  23.2
2009-01-02  27.903  96.198  7.6
2009-01-02  27.876  96.331  8.8
2009-01-02  27.136  95.561  26.8
2009-01-02  28.169  97.031  47.1
2009-01-02  28.18   97.031  30
2009-01-02  25.379  94.2    4.4
2009-01-02  25.297  92.62   4.1
2009-01-02  25.493  92.633  6.8
2009-01-02  25.267  92.731  8.2
2009-01-02  24.814  94.032  3.7
2009-01-02  23.88   91.35   23.6
2009-01-02  25.764  94.834  19.1
2009-01-02  25.762  94.823  10
2009-01-02  25.754  94.835  12.2
2009-01-02  25.544  93.922  5.7
2009-01-02  25.545  93.932  7.2
2009-01-02  26.081  94.447  50.4
2009-01-02  26  94.237  10.3
2009-01-02  26.082  94.457  54.4
2009-01-02  26.038  94.383  6
2009-01-02  26.922  94.412  4.7
2009-01-02  27.091  95.523  31.2
2009-01-02  26.575  94.909  7.8
2009-01-02  26.081  94.371  8
2009-01-02  26.126  94.429  28.7
2009-01-02  27.093  95.535  62.7
2009-01-02  27.066  95.564  41.9
2009-01-02  27.067  95.576  25.9
2009-01-02  26.741  94.657  5.2
2009-01-02  26.945  94.442  10.2
2009-01-02  26.723  95.095  5.9
2009-01-02  26.711  94.69   24.6
2009-01-02  26.712  94.701  13.1
2009-01-02  27.081  95.524  50.3
2009-01-02  26.875  95.256  18.9
2009-01-02  26.949  95.701  28
2009-01-02  27.083  95.536  148.6
2009-01-02  26.885  95.255  13.1
2009-01-02  17.256  73.805  19.4
2009-01-02  14.458  75.149  12.7
2009-01-02  14.382  75.179  29
2009-01-02  14.384  75.194  14.3
2009-01-02  17.797  75.468  19.5
2009-01-02  18.522  74.372  11.7
2009-01-02  19.471  74.682  16.7
2009-01-02  19.867  73.77   13.8
2009-01-02  22.093  74.895  22.4
2009-01-02  23.238  70.078  12.2
2009-01-02  21.657  71.634  6.3
2009-01-02  22.326  69.735  20.5
2009-01-02  22.091  74.876  17.3
2009-01-02  23.77   86.394  9.9
2009-01-02  22.335  82.664  10
2009-01-02  23.795  86.242  6.5
2009-01-03  26.738  95.19   101.8
2009-01-03  26.74   95.178  92.4
2009-01-03  26.926  94.4    5.3
2009-01-03  26.919  95.396  17.9
2009-01-03  27.462  95.472  5.3
2009-01-03  26.604  94.841  31.5
2009-01-03  26.73   95.176  92.3
2009-01-03  26.731  95.183  282.6
2009-01-03  26.733  95.171  14
2009-01-03  26.728  95.188  198.1
2009-01-03  26.725  95.201  24
2009-01-03  26.606  94.827  66.8
2009-01-03  26.59   95.038  200.4
2009-01-03  26.592  95.026  332
2009-01-03  26.58   95.036  33.1
2009-01-03  26.582  95.023  39.6
2009-01-03  26.464  94.993  32.6
2009-01-03  26.598  94.818  49
2009-01-03  26.605  94.835  39.1
2009-01-03  26.472  95.008  14.2
2009-01-03  26.595  94.833  248.5
2009-01-03  26.593  94.846  32.5
2009-01-03  26.75   93.437  5.9
2009-01-03  26.585  94.831  15.1
2009-01-03  26.462  95.007  169.1
2009-01-03  24.847  94.039  5.8
2009-01-03  24.903  94.018  6
2009-01-03  22.064  88.126  4.1
2009-01-03  23.765  86.394  8.8
2009-01-03  23.794  86.242  9.1
2009-01-03  22.792  86.204  15.1
2009-01-03  22.797  86.211  6.3
2009-01-03  17.649  82.549  15.2
2009-01-03  18.028  83.305  11.9
2009-01-03  26.571  95.016  69.5
2009-01-03  26.554  95.022  70.5
2009-01-03  26.567  95.023  122
2009-01-03  26.573  94.795  126.4
2009-01-03  26.581  94.829  87.8
2009-01-03  27.169  95.636  79.1
2009-01-03  26.583  94.826  98.9
2009-01-03  26.575  94.789  89.5
2009-01-03  27.049  95.554  174
2009-01-03  26.601  94.824  74.7
2009-01-03  27.043  95.565  215.6
2009-01-03  27.003  95.54   74.1
2009-01-03  27.161  95.636  63.2
2009-01-03  20.811  70.696  14.8
2009-01-03  21.028  70.314  12.8
2009-01-03  16.92   81.579  9.7
2009-01-03  16.921  81.589  19.7
2009-01-03  17.639  82.551  6.3
2009-01-03  17.025  81.661  13.6
2009-01-03  18.925  84.451  5.7
2009-01-03  17.648  82.55   8
2009-01-03  21.145  79.257  8.6
2009-01-03  21.036  80.534  6.6
2009-01-03  21.034  80.523  12.1
2009-01-03  20.915  81.705  11.3
2009-01-03  20.793  81.214  5.4
2009-01-03  20.935  82.53   7.2
2009-01-03  20.75   81.538  4.4
2009-01-03  19.24   73.212  37.7
2009-01-03  18.247  73.233  54
2009-01-03  19.224  73.215  38.7
2009-01-03  19.234  73.217  61
2009-01-03  22.789  86.208  8.1
2009-01-03  21.896  81.738  28.1
2009-01-03  21.898  81.748  6.7
2009-01-03  21.965  83.226  11.8
2009-01-03  21.916  83.008  8.3
2009-01-03  24.144  82.749  4.8
2009-01-03  24.144  82.619  5.9
2009-01-03  23.502  79.217  27.2
2009-01-03  23.449  83.977  7
2009-01-03  23.504  79.229  9.9
2009-01-03  23.677  80.883  8.3
2009-01-03  22.541  78.06   13.4
2009-01-03  22.905  79.4    27.5
2009-01-03  22.907  79.412  55.2
2009-01-03  23.788  86.241  8.5
2009-01-03  24.205  82.723  3.9
2009-01-03  26.734  91.051  34.8
2009-01-03  25.339  83.562  6.2
2009-01-03  25.345  83.604  4.5
2009-01-03  24.203  82.713  8.1
2009-01-03  26.729  91.047  37.2
2009-01-03  27.489  79.98   3.6
2009-01-03  27.335  82.211  4.5
2009-01-03  27.055  82.58   3.5
2009-01-03  26.618  81.432  4.1
2009-01-03  26.616  81.422  3.1
2009-01-03  27.411  84.093  6.6
2009-01-03  27.142  82.476  5.9
2009-01-03  27.14   82.465  4.8
2009-01-03  27.548  80.001  5.1
2009-01-03  29.693  78.041  4.5
2009-01-03  29.08   78.697  4.4
2009-01-03  29.423  78.646  4.4
2009-01-03  30.167  78.96   6.6
2009-01-03  16.85   74.487  7.7
2009-01-03  14.49   75.963  5.3
2009-01-03  14.016  75.685  5.2
2009-01-03  14.488  75.954  7.5
2009-01-03  16.777  74.678  9.8
2009-01-03  16.05   75.423  4.9
2009-01-03  14.553  75.957  9.6
2009-01-03  16.553  74.653  6.4
2009-01-03  16.024  74.937  5.6
2009-01-03  16.328  75.683  5.7
2009-01-03  16.278  75.345  12.1
2009-01-03  16.326  75.674  5.5
2009-01-03  16.28   75.354  12.7
2009-01-03  19.012  76.563  13.7
2009-01-03  18.129  74.156  12.9
2009-01-03  21.482  76.479  17.4
2009-01-03  23.774  86.394  6.8
2009-01-03  23.796  86.245  7.4
2009-01-04  24.204  82.718  10
2009-01-04  27.454  80.675  9.9
2009-01-04  24.148  82.755  5.7
2009-01-04  21.237  82.138  12.4
2009-01-04  22.331  82.669  7.1
2009-01-04  22.951  78.939  6.7
2009-01-04  24.232  77.153  4.9
2009-01-04  18.949  78.514  4.3
2009-01-04  19.235  77.355  8.1
2009-01-04  20.101  80.64   6.4
2009-01-04  20.003  81.531  7.8
2009-01-04  19.246  76.203  4.7
2009-01-04  18.647  74.71   7.6
2009-01-04  17.715  81.883  21.5
2009-01-04  18.056  75.023  11.1
2009-01-04  17.454  78.463  8.5
2009-01-04  18.022  75.128  8.4
2009-01-04  16.27   75.476  10.7
2009-01-04  16.669  73.538  9.4
2009-01-04  17.324  74.061  9.4
2009-01-04  16.582  74.994  6.2
2009-01-04  16.028  79.044  9.4
2009-01-04  14.129  75.848  6.7
2009-01-04  13.837  75.71   5.3
2009-01-04  13.199  79.451  10.1
2009-01-04  12.591  76.433  4.4
2009-01-04  12.886  75.662  14.5
2009-01-04  9.853   78.415  8.1
2009-01-04  11.841  78.131  9.1
2009-01-04  12.25   76.812  5.3
2009-01-04  10.017  78.233  5.2
2009-01-04  11.525  77.476  6.7
2009-01-04  26.955  94.66   5.6
2009-01-04  25.287  92.521  11.7
2009-01-04  25.289  92.533  13.7
2009-01-04  25.269  92.79   10.4
2009-01-04  26.954  94.65   5.4
2009-01-04  26.868  92.141  16.3
2009-01-04  26.703  91.121  6.9
2009-01-04  27.14   95.548  6.1
2009-01-04  27.183  95.597  18.6
2009-01-04  27.394  94.821  3.2
2009-01-04  26.704  91.062  9.2
2009-01-04  26.702  91.048  35.2
2009-01-04  27.461  95.476  5
2009-01-04  28.172  97.058  7.2
2009-01-04  27.412  94.637  4.9
2009-01-04  27.5    94.734  4.4
2009-01-04  28.131  95.726  11.8
2009-01-04  28.14   95.724  7.2
2009-01-04  9.406   76.562  5.7
2009-01-04  9.353   77.406  10
2009-01-04  10.819  75.955  6.8
2009-01-04  9.602   76.929  8.2
2009-01-04  10.015  76.975  9.1
2009-01-04  9.413   76.564  7.9
2009-01-04  10.96   76.178  7.1
2009-01-04  12.702  76.616  9.9
2009-01-04  12.169  77.27   9.7
2009-01-04  12.424  75.071  13
2009-01-04  12.318  77.168  18.6
2009-01-04  12.32   77.179  6.4
2009-01-04  12.342  77.342  9.9
2009-01-04  12.892  75.661  11
2009-01-04  12.891  75.651  19.8
2009-01-04  14.305  75.496  8.3
2009-01-04  13.769  75.214  9.4
2009-01-04  14.296  75.497  12.4
2009-01-04  14.175  75.43   13.3
2009-01-04  14.036  75.425  49.1
2009-01-04  14.121  75.846  9.5
2009-01-04  16.852  74.502  7.9
2009-01-04  16.459  75.619  9.2
2009-01-04  18.289  75.066  12.3
2009-01-04  21.597  74.211  11.6
2009-01-04  21.571  74.277  19.5
2009-01-04  19.288  77.234  18.5
2009-01-04  18.652  73.817  7.1
2009-01-04  19.397  73.156  7.7
2009-01-04  19.368  73.347  8.6
2009-01-04  19.398  73.166  19.6
2009-01-04  22.959  77.206  11.7
2009-01-04  23.77   86.397  7.3
2009-01-05  26.745  95.228  230.6
2009-01-05  26.588  93.024  2.9
2009-01-05  25.964  92.677  4.2
2009-01-05  26.747  95.217  35.7
2009-01-05  26.744  95.238  24.5
2009-01-05  26.736  95.226  7.1
2009-01-05  25.307  92.768  6.1
2009-01-05  23.723  93.1    8
2009-01-05  21.969  73.088  10
2009-01-05  17.644  75.061  72.9
2009-01-05  17.654  75.045  23.7
2009-01-05  17.648  75.037  32.2
2009-01-05  17.64   75.042  30.1
2009-01-05  17.636  75.066  22.4
2009-01-05  18.011  82.91   8.1
2009-01-05  19.023  81.909  19.7
2009-01-05  21.833  82.367  8
2009-01-05  21.552  81.361  11.3
2009-01-05  21.619  82.44   7
2009-01-05  23.792  86.239  5.9
2009-01-05  22.794  86.205  7.3
2009-01-05  23.768  86.395  8
2009-01-05  23.752  86.418  6.4
2009-01-05  23.679  86.093  5.3
2009-01-05  22.104  80.102  10.1
2009-01-05  24.932  93.888  30.1
2009-01-05  24.931  93.896  29.4
2009-01-05  26.725  93.45   119.7
2009-01-05  26.386  91.242  12.3
2009-01-05  25.348  92.547  17.2
2009-01-05  26.144  94.657  80.3
2009-01-05  25.343  92.54   21.6
2009-01-05  26.151  94.658  93.1
2009-01-05  25.535  93.924  25.1
2009-01-05  24.2    82.721  6.4
2009-01-05  26.068  94.404  31.9
2009-01-05  24.144  82.617  4.9
2009-01-05  26.056  94.414  33.3
2009-01-05  24.203  82.715  7.5
2009-01-05  26.727  93.442  119
2009-01-05  26.729  93.472  30.4
2009-01-05  26.706  90.819  46.5
2009-01-05  26.684  90.841  116.3
2009-01-05  26.831  82.842  9.2
2009-01-05  27.617  80.635  5.2
2009-01-05  27.297  80.743  5.4
2009-01-05  27.513  82.706  7.7
2009-01-05  27.43   80.742  5.5
2009-01-05  27.615  80.622  7.2
2009-01-05  27.994  78.846  5.4
2009-01-05  27.649  80.402  4.9
2009-01-05  27.825  79.764  9.7
2009-01-05  31.311  75.341  13.6
2009-01-05  16.592  74.572  29.4
2009-01-05  16.592  74.578  28.4
2009-01-05  15.779  74.887  35.4
2009-01-05  18.569  74.177  10.1
2009-01-06  26.59   94.879  313.1
2009-01-06  26.593  94.888  216.5
2009-01-06  26.574  94.875  108.6
2009-01-06  25.682  92.467  19.5
2009-01-06  24.142  82.754  5.1
2009-01-06  21.66   82.824  13.6
2009-01-06  21.661  82.815  8.5
2009-01-06  20.82   74.163  16.1
2009-01-06  22.327  82.559  3.8
2009-01-06  21.79   83.897  6
2009-01-06  17.403  80.686  39.2
2009-01-06  17.295  81.669  9.8
2009-01-06  18.761  74.608  16
2009-01-06  17.402  80.696  19.5
2009-01-06  17.296  80.979  4.8
2009-01-06  16.634  75.353  27
2009-01-06  16.682  80.954  6.3
2009-01-06  17.109  81.061  4.7
2009-01-06  16.859  81.379  5
2009-01-06  18.85   83.45   9.7
2009-01-06  18.877  76.451  22.7
2009-01-06  14.658  79.603  6.7
2009-01-06  11.671  79.31   5.2
2009-01-06  11.872  78.935  5.7
2009-01-06  25.211  94.516  21.3
2009-01-06  25.152  94.427  10.3
2009-01-06  26.949  95.115  7.2
2009-01-06  26.936  95.468  10.8
2009-01-06  26.871  95.257  7.4
2009-01-06  26.873  95.586  102.5
2009-01-06  26.591  94.885  42.6
2009-01-06  26.106  94.522  22.1
2009-01-06  26.095  94.522  19.2
2009-01-06  26.588  94.866  62
2009-01-06  26.491  94.726  33.8
2009-01-06  25.954  92.111  32.1
2009-01-06  26.493  94.739  42.6
2009-01-06  26.59   94.878  121.5
2009-01-06  26.578  94.868  166.2
2009-01-06  26.874  95.597  69.1
2009-01-06  26.795  95.24   21.7
2009-01-06  26.587  94.86   17.1
2009-01-06  26.589  94.872  101.5
2009-01-06  26.797  95.253  12.2
2009-01-06  26.436  93.768  3.7
2009-01-06  26.788  95.318  12.1
2009-01-06  27.119  95.574  9.5
2009-01-06  27.121  95.585  7.9
2009-01-06  12.313  77.19   7.1
2009-01-06  12.321  77.309  10.3
2009-01-06  14.307  75.701  6.6
2009-01-06  13.419  76.682  4.2
2009-01-06  12.312  77.181  6.3
2009-01-06  14.029  75.444  11.1
2009-01-06  13.417  76.673  10.7
2009-01-06  13.907  79.809  12.2
2009-01-06  18.393  73.348  8.2
2009-01-06  18.139  73.311  11.3
2009-01-06  15.668  73.812  13.8
2009-01-06  18.732  78.048  19.6
2009-01-06  16.099  75.417  5.4
2009-01-06  17.735  75.321  18.4
2009-01-06  17.711  77.496  17.9
2009-01-06  18.063  73.473  13.4
2009-01-06  18.105  74.345  5.4
2009-01-06  18.046  74.501  7.2
2009-01-06  18.559  74.298  12.3
2009-01-06  18.689  74.796  7.1
2009-01-06  18.558  74.288  9.3
2009-01-06  19.273  75.969  16.8
2009-01-06  19.194  77.198  13.5
2009-01-06  18.799  73.124  13
2009-01-06  22.183  72.793  11.8
2009-01-06  21.56   74.081  8.9
2009-01-06  21.298  74.997  12.1
2009-01-06  19.474  74.684  10.8
2009-01-06  21.243  77.127  17.5
2009-01-06  20.29   73.796  10.7
2009-01-06  19.391  73.302  6
2009-01-06  19.531  74.326  11.1
2009-01-06  19.389  73.291  9.2
2009-01-06  19.682  75.095  8
2009-01-06  22.196  75.883  12.6
2009-01-06  22.198  75.893  8.3
2009-01-06  21.486  73.3    18.4
2009-01-06  24.651  73.848  5.9
2009-01-06  27.367  79.811  12.1
2009-01-06  27.364  79.817  9.9
2009-01-06  28.453  76.883  7.6
2009-01-06  28.299  77.743  5.8
2009-01-06  30.525  76.275  7.7
2009-01-06  29.257  75.721  8.5
2009-01-06  30.226  77.207  8.1
2009-01-06  30.06   76.727  9.6
2009-01-06  31.069  76.231  5.6
2009-01-06  31.146  75.763  9
2009-01-06  31.147  75.775  12.5
2009-01-06  31.134  75.924  4.4
2009-01-06  31.134  75.919  4.9
2009-01-06  31.901  75.538  5.9
2009-01-06  31.668  75.879  4.4
2009-01-06  31.94   75.679  4.6
2009-01-06  16.41   75.43   19.9
2009-01-06  21.107  72.643  15.2
2009-01-07  26.763  95.358  5.3
2009-01-07  26.421  94.951  46.2
2009-01-07  26.768  95.364  73.1
2009-01-07  26.77   95.353  69
2009-01-07  26.778  95.365  22.2
2009-01-07  26.776  95.376  12.1
2009-01-07  26.422  94.94   11.5
2009-01-07  26.485  94.793  34.4
2009-01-07  26.486  94.781  23.2
2009-01-07  26.537  94.694  6.7
2009-01-07  26.527  94.692  52.2
2009-01-07  25.275  92.782  9.9
2009-01-07  25.259  93.844  9.3
2009-01-07  30.094  76.846  8.9
2009-01-07  30.255  76.869  7.3
2009-01-07  29.017  79.432  28.5
2009-01-07  29.518  77.312  5.3
2009-01-07  22.145  73.41   6
2009-01-07  22.186  75.544  11.3
2009-01-07  21.905  72.763  13.5
2009-01-07  21.907  72.754  24.1
2009-01-07  21.366  73.141  5
2009-01-07  21.908  72.683  9.5
2009-01-07  21.58   72.953  5.2
2009-01-07  21.092  73.243  8.1
2009-01-07  20.958  70.452  6.3
2009-01-07  19.125  74.061  11.1
2009-01-07  16.354  75.191  17.5
2009-01-07  18.73   74.148  6.2
2009-01-07  22.76   86.239  6.1
2009-01-07  23.545  93.341  7.8
2009-01-07  21.353  83.216  10.4
2009-01-07  24.638  93.827  7.9
2009-01-07  24.644  93.821  15
2009-01-07  25.706  92.896  8.4
2009-01-07  26.479  94.798  44.3
2009-01-07  26.521  94.829  38.1
2009-01-07  26.466  94.798  40.3
2009-01-07  26.074  94.388  21.4
2009-01-07  26.477  94.779  90.2
2009-01-07  26.496  94.704  23.3
2009-01-07  26.466  94.791  62.3
2009-01-07  26.479  94.792  72.7
2009-01-07  26.508  94.831  22.5
2009-01-07  26.477  94.771  81.5
2009-01-07  26.258  88.947  5
2009-01-07  26.87   94.42   15.1
2009-01-07  26.871  94.425  15.5
2009-01-07  26.774  95.444  436.6
2009-01-07  26.875  95.571  24.7
2009-01-07  26.627  93.189  60.1
2009-01-07  26.356  91.241  8.1
2009-01-07  26.765  95.35   20.3
2009-01-07  27.491  81.984  12.7
2009-01-07  26.814  92.201  8.3
2009-01-07  26.678  91.053  6.2
2009-01-07  27.494  82.001  10.1
2009-01-07  26.677  91.04   6.3
2009-01-07  27.359  83.661  17.4
2009-01-07  26.748  91.126  4.9
2009-01-07  26.696  90.781  6.3
2009-01-07  26.741  91.153  43.7
2009-01-07  26.719  91.144  5.9
2009-01-07  26.742  91.166  17.7
2009-01-07  28.892  80.026  14
2009-01-07  21.903  72.74   33.6
2009-01-07  19.007  76.422  12.7
2009-01-07  16.351  75.214  18.9
2009-01-07  16.353  75.197  21
2009-01-07  16.859  81.582  6.1
2009-01-07  21.904  72.759  32.2
2009-01-07  21.907  72.757  21.3
2009-01-08  30.002  78.98   22.7
2009-01-08  22.792  86.209  4.2
2009-01-08  23.67   84.998  4.8
2009-01-08  23.77   86.398  8.7
2009-01-08  23.793  86.243  7.6
2009-01-08  20.871  85.86   6.4
2009-01-08  21.196  81.415  20.3
2009-01-08  21.194  81.408  8.5
2009-01-08  21.192  81.421  15.4
2009-01-08  26.482  94.737  221.1
2009-01-08  26.482  94.871  61.8
2009-01-08  26.485  94.887  71
2009-01-08  26.473  94.89   172.4
2009-01-08  26.469  94.872  126.3
2009-01-08  26.483  94.73   268.5
2009-01-08  26.487  94.751  24.9
2009-01-08  26.478  94.716  76.8
2009-01-08  26.785  95.129  100.7
2009-01-08  26.789  95.148  38.5
2009-01-08  27.031  95.25   16.8
2009-01-08  26.915  95.581  38.8
2009-01-08  27.027  95.267  11.5
2009-01-08  27.024  95.247  10
2009-01-08  16.628  81.06   5.6
2009-01-08  14.053  75.793  12.3
2009-01-08  16.685  81.159  7.3
2009-01-08  17.266  80.762  11
2009-01-08  17.283  73.85   20.8
2009-01-08  17.267  80.772  7.5
2009-01-08  17.257  80.764  8.2
2009-01-08  17.893  78.051  19.5
2009-01-08  16.45   73.655  26.3
2009-01-08  16.842  76.677  10.9
2009-01-08  16.356  73.643  23.6
2009-01-08  17.2    73.85   16.2
2009-01-08  17.35   78.616  6.1
2009-01-08  18.022  80.044  7.7
2009-01-08  18.11   74.648  21.8
2009-01-08  18.273  79.928  6
2009-01-08  18.603  80.603  5.7
2009-01-08  19.125  78.855  7.3
2009-01-08  19.331  77.248  7.6
2009-01-08  22.041  73.044  27.6
2009-01-08  21.237  75.046  19.5
2009-01-08  22.042  73.049  30
2009-01-08  21.335  74.83   10.7
2009-01-08  21.275  75.16   5.6
2009-01-08  21.333  74.825  7.3
2009-01-08  25.861  78.206  8.3
2009-01-08  25.323  77.064  5
2009-01-08  28.158  79.637  5.8
2009-01-08  27.664  77.464  5.5
2009-01-08  25.221  72.899  23.6
2009-01-08  25.86   78.196  6.8
2009-01-08  25.788  77.674  4
2009-01-08  28.268  80.298  5
2009-01-08  29.703  77.445  10.8
2009-01-08  29.641  77.463  6.2
2009-01-08  29.325  77.706  4.7
2009-01-08  29.446  77.52   4.3
2009-01-08  29.208  77.591  5.1
2009-01-08  28.856  78.401  5.9
2009-01-08  28.696  78.165  5.3
2009-01-08  28.584  79.97   9.7
2009-01-08  28.465  78.29   5.1
2009-01-08  29.107  77.319  3.9
2009-01-08  29.126  79.243  17.3
2009-01-08  28.747  77.112  3.4
2009-01-08  28.884  77.442  10.6
2009-01-08  29.242  78.931  6.4
2009-01-08  28.98   78.088  5
2009-01-08  28.978  78.077  5.5
2009-01-08  29.184  76.357  14.1
2009-01-08  29.308  77.378  4.1
2009-01-08  30.175  77.2    6.2
2009-01-08  29.898  77.122  5
2009-01-08  29.891  77.129  11.1
2009-01-08  29.702  77.434  5.7
2009-01-08  29.734  77.331  5.5
2009-01-08  30.452  77.07   9.7
2009-01-08  30.453  77.081  4.6
2009-01-08  30.806  76.764  7.8
2009-01-08  31.543  78.043  12.1
2009-01-08  30.815  76.763  7.8
2009-01-08  31.675  75.607  4
2009-01-08  31.804  75.042  6.4
2009-01-08  31.932  74.721  5.4
2009-01-08  28.172  97.067  18.7
2009-01-08  14.02   75.681  9.7
2009-01-08  16.696  74.567  13
2009-01-08  18.564  74.522  9.5
2009-01-08  16.726  74.644  9.7
2009-01-08  16.727  74.649  10.7
2009-01-08  21.906  72.685  6.9
2009-01-08  21.154  72.733  7.1
2009-01-08  22.801  86.222  14.7
2009-01-08  22.803  86.209  32.5
2009-01-08  23.77   86.398  8.5
2009-01-08  22.793  86.215  13.2
2009-01-08  21.195  81.419  9.5
2009-01-09  26.49   94.91   40
2009-01-09  26.752  95.338  58.2
2009-01-09  26.11   94.537  26.1
2009-01-09  26.488  94.93   7.7
2009-01-09  30.184  80.271  14.8
2009-01-09  28.296  79.685  4.9
2009-01-09  28.825  79.065  6.6
2009-01-09  19.245  75.052  5.8
2009-01-09  21.114  75.44   4.5
2009-01-09  21.151  76.444  18.3
2009-01-09  21.153  76.434  15
2009-01-09  22.219  75.995  6.8
2009-01-09  20.759  73.15   6.9
2009-01-09  20.099  73.713  10.3
2009-01-09  19.149  76.256  8.9
2009-01-09  20.09   73.712  9.9
2009-01-09  18.552  77.03   7.3
2009-01-09  18.702  73.563  4.6
2009-01-09  18.703  73.553  4.8
2009-01-09  18.656  73.814  3.6
```

So could you please provide some information that how can I convert into netcdf in R.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445214/how-can-i-save-a-3-column-data-frame-into-a-netcdf-file-in-r

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the given code is not suitable for my data.

Answer (score 1):

The package `ncdf4` will help you achieve this. Here is the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/ncdf4.pdf) for creating a netCDF file by defining the dimensions and variables from the dataframe.

Here is the sample code that I tried to create 3 dimensional netCDF.

**Data used:**

```
lat,long,time
41,-109,6
40,-107,18
39,-105,6
41,-103,18
40,-109,6
39,-107,18
```

**Sample code:**

```
library(ncdf4)

#Collect individual columns
xvals <- df$long
yvals <- df$lat
time <- df$time

#Create dimension definition
lon_dim <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_east", xvals)
lat_dim <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_north", yvals)
time_dim <- ncdim_def("time","h",unique(time))

#Define new variable and append with 0
mv =  1.e30
frp <- ncvar_def("frp", "frp", list(lon1,lat2,time_dim), mv)
frp

#Create a netCDF file
ncnew = nc_create("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\my_nc.nc", frp)
ncnew
```

You can use `ncvar_put` function to add the values of frp. The documentation is clean and precise. It should be helpful. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting an error. in your code `mv = ?` ,  `( mv= 0 )`. If I put the 0 value here and follow the given steps. But its not creating the correct file. After creating ncnew I am getting the file size 1.5 gb.

Comment: Im sorry about that. Can you try `mv = 1.e30` as given in the documentation? With the dataset I mentioned above, I only get 1KB file created.

Comment: the file has converted into .nc but it's not giving any values.

Comment: Can you share your output. If there is no errors, there should be some data. can you be more specific on what data is missing? is it the dimensions or the variables data that is missing?